# how to add the class="last" to the last line in the loop

Tags: php

the above is form the database, which used the LIMIT 0, 10.($result)

```
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                   echo '<li>'.$row->title.'</li>';
          }
```

now i want to add the class="last" to the 10 line. this is my ways. but it can't work. how to correct it or using another way to get that?

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
      $num=0;
      if($num==9){
                   echo '<li class="last">'.$row->title'</li>';
          }else{ echo '<li>'.$row->title.'</li>';}
       $num++;
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `$num=0;` outside the `while` loop.

You are defining `$num=0;` inside `while` so `++$num;` has no meaning at all. It will set to `0`.

Well, the logic is like this.

```
$j = 0; /* $j is outside the loop, so it does not repeat. */    

for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{   
    $k = 0;     
    /*      
    Its because the loop repeats,
    And $k is set to 0 at the above step.        
    */      
    echo "j: ".($j++)." k:".($k++)."<br/>"; 
}
```

Comment: got it, why i should put the $num=0 outside the while loop. thank you

Answer (score 1):

In order to know if you are on the last line of your resultset, you have to know how many lines there are in that resultset *(as, of course, **you could have less than 10 rows**)* ; two possible solutions :

- Use a `select count()` query, with the same `where` clause as your `select` query that gets you the data, to find out if you have less than 10 rows, or more than 10 rows.
- Or fetch the whole resultset to an array first, and, only after that, display it -- using [`count()`](https://www.php.net/count) to know how many rows there are in that array.

Another possibility could be to use the [**`mysql_num_rows()`**][2] function, to get the total number of rows -- which will allow you to know if you're on the last one *(quoting)* :

> Retrieves the number of rows from a
> result set. This command is only valid
> for statements like `SELECT` or `SHOW`
> that return an actual result set.

In any case, you'll then have to keep track of the number of lines you've displayed -- to know if you are on the last one.

Note : this means using some counter variable as you did ; except you'll want to **initialize it to 0 outside of the loop** !

Else, reseting to 0 each time you loop, you'll never know on which line you are !

Answer (score 1):

```
using another way
```

using css

```
li:last-child{
/*add properties of that class(last) here*/
}
```